# Django dynamic css implementation: only one item changes (background) dynamically. How to?

Tags: css, django, dynamic

I would like to set up one single css style which gets the background dynamically
from some django variable.

I think the added difficulty is that it is related to a:hover.

The original static style.css code runs like:

```
.titles-button h2 a {
    margin-left: 4em;
    margin-right: 4em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    display: block;
    width: 240px;
    height: 80px;
    /* background: transparent url(../logos/djangoVX_logo.png) center left no-repeat; */
    text-indent: -999em;
    border: 1px dashed green;
}
.titles-button h2 a:hover {
    /* background: transparent url(../logos/djangoVX_logo2.png) center left no-repeat; */
}
```

Note the background is now commented.

I would like to use this style within a DIV and update dynamically the background.

Like:

```
{% if the_apps_list %}
    {% for apps in the_apps_list %}
    <div class="titles-button"> 
        <h2><a href="/{{ apps.app_name }}/" style="X">{{ apps.app_name }}</a></h2> 
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No APPS are available. Internal Error.</p>
{% endif %}
```

I did my best for "X" but with no results.

With the exception of:
 - Rewrite the full style in X
 - Use some javascript fancy stuff (on_mouse_over...)
 - I have even seen a class: inheritALL

None of this solution fits my idea of using django.

I might get the bull from the wrong side...

..which one is the right side?

cheers
F

Comment: please explain the behavior you are trying to achieve. Why wouldn't your original css work?

Comment: The original CSS works. What I am trying to do is to have django to update/refresh/overwrite the background portion dynamically. I.e. keep everything from the style except updating the background. I have a solution using 'onmouseover' and friends. But I still have problems with inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have "dark" and "light" versions of background. Your code may look like:

**views.py:**

```
...
if i_want_dark_version:
    context['style']='dark'
else:
    context['style']='light'
```

**template.html:**

```
<div id="titles-button" class="{{ style }}">
    ...
</div>
```

**style.css:**

```
#titles-button.dark h2 a {
    background: ...;
}
#titles-button.dark h2 a:hover {
    background: ...;
}

#titles-button.light h2 a {
    background: ...;
}
#titles-button.light h2 a:hover {
    background: ...;
}
```

Comment: This would be perfect for 2 versions. What about 100?

Comment: Sorry I am a bit new to stackoverflow. I thought I wrote a bit more.

Comment: Can you forgive the lines before (if any). I want to achieve: A given fixed style with a and a:hover backgrounds defined by django. Actually django probably is not even the point: what ever dynamic HTML renderer. But if as I mentioned I get the bull from the wrong side,

Comment: ..if I get the bull from the wrong side, is there a better way to use CSS and django? What I want is a list (series of divs) which have an <a> mark which allow for a mouse over (a:hover). The actual pics are given from django. This is not simply a 2 possibilities: this is the full list of pictures.

Comment: You have quite hard use case here. I don't know how to solve it using only html, css and Django without generating lot of messy code. Try to rethink your approach. It seems that you are generating parts of your user interface (background) dynamically. Are you sure that this is best approach? What if user add images that are not suitable for background? Remember that if your UI have lot of different elements it can be hard to understand for user. Also weight of your page rise.

Comment: Actually  this was part of the question... redesign.

Comment: Actually  this was part of the question... redesign. But here the user is the admin of the site. i.e. he wants that background right there. To be more clear. The 'very simple' application allows the user to add content like in a ul/li list. Each 'li' will allow for a different background which comes up from the loop. This in the template.. but I would like to fix the CSS style for the rest of the 'li' properties. i.e. it will be a kinda list of boxes with given style and loop dependent background.

Comment: Not sure in general (I guess it works) but definitely with 'a' link and 'a:hover' style I have problems... the current solution uses onmouseover='' but as you pointed out it is a lot of more code and less prone to eventual future changes. I can redesign of course.. but how?

Comment: I posted a new problem, question. Maybe a bit Idiotic. Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158215/django-css-practice-what-in-and-what-out-what

Comment: Hoi Tomas, it is not an hard case. It should be standard django. Can you post your experience. It might not solve my problem but maybe I get some hints. #tomas